# Marking duplicate entries in a numpy array as True

Tags: python, array, numpy

So the problem is

> Find the duplicate entries (2nd occurrence onwards) in the given numpy
> array and mark them as True. First time occurrences should be False.

And my solution is:

```
import numpy as np


def duplicates(a):
    uniques = np.unique(a)
    result = []
    for i in a:
        if i not in uniques:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
            uniques = np.delete(uniques, np.where(uniques == i))
    return result


np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)
print('Array: ', a)
print(duplicates(a))
```

What improvments can i make in this program?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your question. I answered it but I edited it a bunch of times, so be sure to check the final version of the answer now. Let me know in the comments if you have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good code, I'd say. There's nothing wrong with it. The only thing is that you can write more or less the same algorithm in a much shorter way, and that essentially means you would refactor all of your code down to a single line.

So, before taking a look at the boiled down version of what you wrote, let me just point out that variable names should be descriptive and if you are using abbreviations or one-letter names, you should stick to the **most** used conventions. Why am I saying this? Well, `i` is typically the name for an unimportant *index* variable, but in your loop you have `for i in a`, and `i` is an element of the array... So, believe it or not, people looking at the
rest of your code might be thrown off by the fact that `i` is not an index.

**Intermediate step**

So before jumping to the one-liner that is actually *readable* (i.e. it is good Python code) let's take a look at a more tractable intermediate step. Instead of computing all the unique values and then deleting from there (deleting from the middle of a list is typically "slow), you could go the other way around and have a list that saves all the unique values you have found:

```py
def duplicates(arr):
    result, uniques = [], []
    for elem in arr:
        if elem in uniques:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
            uniques.append(elem)
    
    return result
```

**Next intermediate step**

Now take another look at what I wrote.
Notice that both in the `if` and the `else` I am appending to the `result` variable. The only thing that is really "special" is the appending to the `uniques`, which only happens on the `else`, so we could write the `.append` unconditionally and append to `uniques` only if needed:

```py
def duplicates(arr):
    result, uniques = [], []
    for elem in arr:
        result.append(elem in uniques)
        if elem in not uniques:
            uniques.append(elem)
    
    return result
```

**Final solution (after rethinking algorithm)**

Let me know if you can understand my suggested solution and I'll expand on it if you need :)

```py
def duplicates(arr):
    return [elem in arr[:i] for i, elem in enumerate(arr)]
```

Notice that this list comprehension reads "return a list that says if the i-th element can be found in the first i-1 elements".

The key here is in phrasing the result in the correct way. If you reason Python code in the correct way, English and the code become one and the same.

When you have a relatively simple `for` loop that is building a list with successive `.append`, that's a sign to try and see if you can use a list comprehension.

I am also making use of the `enumerate` built-in ([learn about it here](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/enumerate-me)) to traverse the array while looking at the values and indices at the same time.

**EDIT**:

As other answers have noted (and also, see comments on this answer), this one-liner runs in time complexity O(n^2), which is not the best you can do.
However, that single line of Python shows you how far you can go with just a simple idea/naive algorithm, and optimised usage of the core features of Python :)

Comment: In that case it should be False, True, True. The False value is given only to the first appearance of the value in the array. Thank you for your explanation and advices, I really appreciate being in this community :)

Comment: @LevonAvetisyan yup, I looked more calmly at your code and understood that, of course!

Comment: Better make `uniques` a `set`.

Comment: @Manuel better performance in checking if the element is already there? (Won't the performance to _add_ a new element be worse?) Or why would you suggest that?

Comment: Yes, making the whole thing O(n) instead of O(n^2). Plus you can remove your extra check then.

Comment: @Manuel interesting suggestion. Still doesn't beat the list comprehension in simplicity...

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments of another answer, you should use `set`s for membership tests whenever possible. Combinig this with building up `uniques` instead of cutting it down, we get this really simple implementation:

```
def duplicates(numbers):
    uniques = set()
    result = []

    for num in numbers:
        result.append(num in uniques)
        uniques.add(num)

    return result
```

This implementation of `duplicates` is concise, easy to read and runs in O(n) instead of O(n^2), which is a major difference. One-liners are a fun exercise that can teach you some interesting aspects of Python, and I understand their appeal, but they're often not the best way to go. It's not worth sacrificing readability and performance for the sake of writing less lines of code.

---

**EDIT: Performance testing**

As requested in the comments I tested the performance of three different approaches:

```
def duplicates_set(numbers):
    uniques = set()
    result = []

    for num in numbers:
        result.append(num in uniques)
        uniques.add(num)

    return result


def duplicates_list(numbers):
    result, uniques = [], []
    for elem in numbers:
        if elem in uniques:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
            uniques.append(elem)

    return result


def duplicates_oneliner(numbers):
    return [elem in numbers[:i] for i, elem in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Note that the following approach for `duplicates_list` should be avoided in any case, since it checks for `elem` membership in `uniques` twice.

```
def duplicates_list(numbers):
    result, uniques = [], []
    for elem in numbers:
        result.append(elem in uniques)
        if elem not in uniques:
            uniques.append(elem)

    return result
```

---

Here is my code for performance testing using the `timeit` module. All the provided outputs were produced by this code.

```
num_range: (int, int)
random_nums: int
executions: int

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.randint(*num_range, random_nums)

from timeit import timeit

print(f"{executions} executions with {random_nums} random numbers in range {num_range}")
print("duplicates_set:", "\t" * 2, timeit(stmt=lambda: duplicates_set(a), number=executions))
print("duplicates_list:", "\t" * 2, timeit(stmt=lambda: duplicates_list(a), number=executions))
print("duplicates_oneliner:\t", timeit(stmt=lambda: duplicates_oneliner(a), number=executions))
```

Starting out with 100_000 executions with the parameters from the original question we get this result:

```
100000 executions with 10 random numbers in range (0, 5)
duplicates_set:          0.22261620000000001
duplicates_list:         0.18974730000000006
duplicates_oneliner:     2.9783912
```

We can clearly see that the `list` implementation performs the best for a small amount of numbers and a small range of random numbers. The one-liner is already at a huge disadvantage.

Upping the length of the random number array to 1_000, we get this result:

```
1000 executions with 1000 random numbers in range (0, 5)
duplicates_set:          0.1603748
duplicates_list:         0.13001250000000003
duplicates_oneliner:     3.1837349
```

It seems the length of the array alone does not really affect the relative performance of `duplicates_set` and `duplicates_list`. As long as the range of numbers is small, the `list` comes out on top. Relative performance stayed the same up until 1_000_000 elements, which makes sense since the size of `uniques` is capped by the range of numbers.

Once we start increasing `num_range`, the `set` implementation really starts to shine, since it simply does not care about the size of `uniques` when it comes to runtime:

```
1000 executions with 1000 random numbers in range (0, 10)
duplicates_set:          0.15972010000000003
duplicates_list:         0.15932980000000002
duplicates_oneliner:     3.1950098
```

For a range of `(0, 10)`, `set` and `list` implementation perform about the same.

At a range of `(0, 1_000)` the `list` implementation is already outperformed by the one-liner:

```
1000 executions with 1000 random numbers in range (0, 1000)
duplicates_set:          0.15644170000000002
duplicates_list:         3.4406095
duplicates_oneliner:     3.1854200999999995
```

The one-liner however is immediately out of the competition once the input gets larger, even at small number ranges:

```
10 executions with 100000 random numbers in range (0, 10)
duplicates_set:          0.1576303
duplicates_list:         0.24761889999999998
duplicates_oneliner:     30.1282213
```

The final result is exactly what would be expected:

- `duplicates_list` really starts to struggle once the number of unique numbers goes up, since `if elem in uniques` gets increasingly expensive.
- `duplicates_oneliner` completely breaks down with long input lists, since `elem in numbers[:i]` gets expensive really fast.
- `duplicates_set` is only outperformed at a low number of unique numbers, but at scale it outperforms both other implementations by a huge margin, since `if elem in uniques` can be checked in constant time.

Comment: I agree that your solution is concise and legible and I like your unconditional `uniques.add`, well played! +1 from me :)

Comment: However, you do seem to imply my solution is nor readable nor performant. While it is a fact that its complexity is O(n^2) and therefore less performant, I think we can agree that single line is still very legible and showcases nicely how far you can go with a fairly naive algorithm.
Finally, I wonder if the solution using `set` really is O(n) if the array has too many unique elements. I would expect either `set` to use _way to much memory_ to be O(1) in insertion and membership checking or to be something like O(log n) for membership checking, no? Do you have references for me to learn? :)

Comment: @RGS You're right in that `set`s use more memory than lists, since hash values values need to be stored in addition to the elements themselves. [Memory comparison on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914266/memory-consumption-of-a-list-and-set-in-python). Your assumption regarding membership checking not being O(1) is incorrect though. `set`s (and `dict`s) are implemented using hash tables, providing O(1) lookups and insertions. [Chapter 4 in *High Performance Python*: Dictionaries and Sets](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-python/9781449361747/ch04.html)

Comment: @RGS I also added the results of a bit of performance testing to my answer.

Comment: Could you include my solution in the benchmarks?

Comment: @RGS That unconditional `add` is btw what I meant with "Plus you can remove your extra check then". After that, I suspect the one-liner and the set-solution are about equally readable in general, and the one-liner more readable for people used to them :-)

Comment: Oh well, added benchmarks to my answer now (same cases as yours).

Answer (score 6):

Check out `unique`'s [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) again, it offers to give you indices:

```
def duplicates(a):
    uniques = np.unique(a, True)[1]
    result = a == a
    result[uniques] = False
    return result
```

In benchmarks (reusing [riskypenguin's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/259477/230375)) it's medium for the tiny original case but by far fastest for all larger cases:

```
100000 executions with 10 random numbers in range (0, 5)
duplicates_original  17.807 17.395 18.284 seconds
duplicates_set        0.726  0.686  0.721 seconds
duplicates_list       0.631  0.548  0.587 seconds
duplicates_oneliner   7.087  6.946  7.822 seconds
duplicates_numpy      2.017  2.177  2.155 seconds

1000 executions with 1000 random numbers in range (0, 5)
duplicates_original   6.904  6.862  6.617 seconds
duplicates_set        0.520  0.535  0.584 seconds
duplicates_list       0.385  0.363  0.341 seconds
duplicates_oneliner   7.241  7.927  7.244 seconds
duplicates_numpy      0.062  0.065  0.063 seconds

1000 executions with 1000 random numbers in range (0, 10)
duplicates_original   6.720  6.885  6.801 seconds
duplicates_set        0.656  0.542  0.576 seconds
duplicates_list       0.459  0.511  0.509 seconds
duplicates_oneliner   7.556  7.064  7.637 seconds
duplicates_numpy      0.080  0.082  0.073 seconds

1000 executions with 1000 random numbers in range (0, 1000)
duplicates_original  25.222 26.108 24.767 seconds
duplicates_set        0.682  0.757  0.759 seconds
duplicates_list      11.608 11.651 11.196 seconds
duplicates_oneliner   8.320  7.949  7.608 seconds
duplicates_numpy      0.101  0.110  0.102 seconds

10 executions with 100000 random numbers in range (0, 10)
duplicates_original   6.577  6.658  6.637 seconds
duplicates_set        0.609  0.585  0.603 seconds
duplicates_list       0.514  0.524  0.508 seconds
duplicates_oneliner  36.337 36.677 35.764 seconds
duplicates_numpy      0.082  0.083  0.083 seconds
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

def duplicates_original(a):
    uniques = np.unique(a)
    result = []
    for i in a:
        if i not in uniques:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
            uniques = np.delete(uniques, np.where(uniques == i))
    return result

def duplicates_set(numbers):
    uniques = set()
    result = []

    for num in numbers:
        result.append(num in uniques)
        uniques.add(num)

    return result

def duplicates_list(numbers):
    result, uniques = [], []
    for elem in numbers:
        if elem in uniques:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
            uniques.append(elem)

    return result

def duplicates_oneliner(numbers):
    return [elem in numbers[:i] for i, elem in enumerate(numbers)]

def duplicates_numpy(a):
    uniques = np.unique(a, True)[1]
    result = a == a
    result[uniques] = False
    return result

def benchmark(num_range: (int, int), random_nums: int, executions: int):

    np.random.seed(100)
    a = np.random.randint(*num_range, random_nums)

    print(f"{executions} executions with {random_nums} random numbers in range {num_range}")

    solutions = [
        duplicates_original,
        duplicates_set,
        duplicates_list,
        duplicates_oneliner,
        duplicates_numpy,
    ]

    # Correctness
    expect = list(solutions[0](a))
    for solution in solutions:
        assert list(solution(a)) == expect

    # Speed
    for solution in solutions:
        ts = ['%6.3f' % timeit(stmt=lambda: solution(a), number=executions)
              for _ in range(3)]
        print(solution.__name__.ljust(20), *ts, 'seconds')
    print()

benchmark((0, 5), 10, 100000)
benchmark((0, 5), 1000, 1000)
benchmark((0, 10), 1000, 1000)
benchmark((0, 1000), 1000, 1000)
benchmark((0, 10), 100000, 10)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution as well! Knowing your library functions is important :) +1

Comment: Although I would suggest renaming `uniques` to something that says you have indices, and not values, so `uniques_idx` or smth like that. Also, might I suggest then `_, idx = np.unique(a, True)`? I'd argue you shouldn't unpack with indices when you can avoid it.

Comment: @RGS And here I was, thinking `a == a` would be what people would complain about :-D

Comment: I've been doing a lot of array oriented programming in APL lately, so `a == a` doesn't shock me that much :p

Comment: Really interesting benchmarks, `numpy` shines once again!

Comment: @riskypenguin Well, it was supposed to, especially since the input is a numpy array :-). I'm actually disappointed it lost at the small case.

Comment: @riskypenguin Included the original solution as well now (should always be done, in my opinion) and it's rather slow. Shows that using numpy doesn't automatically mean fast, stil need to do it "right" :-)

Comment: Absolutely, that's a good point. Will include the original in the future!